# Finding other orders of triple integrals.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I find it insanely hard to imagine and change the order of integration for triple integrals. I have this problem for example. $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{y^3}\int_{0}^{y^2}f(x,y,z) dzdxdy$ So it is easy to change this to dzdydx because that only looking at the area at the bottom. However, changing it to anything else seems very hard, and requires sketching the volume. Could anyone tell me how to approach this problem, and problems like this in the future?

Thank you.

Comment: Your range of integration for $y$ is from $0$ to $y^2$. That makes no sense....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Typo, sorry

Comment: Just write equations for the domain of integration, then "solve them with respect to the one or the other order". In the above we have $y\in[0,2]$ first, then i have no idea which variable moves in $[0,y^2]$, it can be $x$, it can be $z$... better write the integral by making clear which variable moves first, e.g. $$ \int_{0}^{2}dy\int_{0}^{y^2}dx\int_{0}^{y^3}f(x,y,z) dz\ ,$$and the equations for this would be $0\le 2\le y$, $0\le x\le y^2$, $0\le z\le y^3$. So $x\in[0,4]$, $z\in[0,8]$, and if $z$ is first, then write $\int_0^8dz\dots$ and so on. Solving w.r.t. $y$... $z^{1/3}\le y\le 2$...

Comment: @dan_fulea I think the problem is, I consider these problems inherently visual. I am completely lost if we are to do it purely algebraically

Comment: @dan_fulea: Perhaps as physicist you're used to that notation, but mathematicians — and calculus books — are perfectly fine with the OP's notation. What you wrote down is *not* what the OP wrote. ... And it's not as easy as you make it out to be to switch the order.

Comment: @Sorfosh: You might find some of the examples in days 5 and 6 of my YouTube [MATH 3510 lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exmZ4nuWGM4&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) useful. I'll try to write out something for your question here.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Well, the OP wrote something that is unclear. To see why, which is the variable moving from $0$ to $2$? I am not a physicist, the above is my way to avoid parentheses, still having no problems with the order of variables. The other way would be $$\int_{y\in[0,2]}\int_{x\in[0,y^2]}\dots$$ So what is your preference?! Just "expose" an answer, then we can discust about its general taste. Things have been edited... and $dzdxdy$ is/was not readable without spaces like $dz \, dx\, dy$...

Comment: Oh good grief, @dan_fulea. One pairs integrals with "differentials" working from outside to inside, and you're being ridiculous if you complain about missing spaces. Everyone can read this. I admit that in my published textbook I was careful to put in the little bit of extra space, but clarity is not at issue here.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: I said something is **not readable**, i did not complain, just read something like "How to type in (La)TeX?!" Your textbook is not part of the discussion. You do not answer or comment the question, but parts of the comments that are not realted to the question. To keep working with math, take a look, for instance, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus) and the many lines where the typist was using the one or the other way. Yes, it is common to use it in physics, and it is often useful to use the same notation in maths.

Comment: @dan_fulea They mention on that very Wikipedia page that that notation is used commonly in physics and you are off topic, so please stop.

Comment: @Sorfosh As i said, "yes", it is commonly used in physics, and also in mathematics, this is no contradiction, theorems I, II in loc. cit. "very" use it. The notation is an important part of mathematics, and this was really related to the question. Please note that the present answer isolates the inequalities of the domain. A possible way to be compact by notation is by using $$\iiint_{\substack{0\le y\le 2\\0\le x\le y^2\le 4\\0\le z\le y^3\le 8}}=\iiint_{\substack{(x,y)\in[0,4]\times[0,8]\\x^{1/2},z^{1/3}\le y\le 2}}\ .$$And the easy change is to $dx\, dz\, dy$! One more reason for form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to convert the iterated integrals to a multiple integral. For instance,

$$ \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{y^3}\int_{0}^{y^2} f(x,y,z)\,dzdxdy
= \iiint_{\mathcal{D}} f(x,y,z) \, dxdydz $$

where $\mathcal{D}$ is a region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by

$$\mathcal{D} = \{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 0 \leq y \leq 2, \ 0 \leq x \leq y^3, \ 0 \leq z \leq y^2 \}$$

Now, for instance, say you want to convert this to the iterated integrals in the order of $dydxdz$. This requires both geometric intuition and algebraic manipulation. The key idea here is to convert this set of inequalities, while not changing the region this set describes, to another so that

- $z$ is free of $x, y$, and
- $x$ is free of $y$.

To do this, we first need to figure out the range of $z$. This is easily obtained from $0\leq z\leq y^2$ and $0 \leq y \leq 2$. These together yield $0 \leq z \leq 4$, and it is clear that $z$ can take any values in-between.

Next, given $0 \leq z \leq 4$, we want to figure out the range of $x$ possibly depending on $z$ but not on $y$. This can be done in a similar manner, yielding $0 \leq x \leq 8$. (The fact that the range of $x$ given $z$ is independent of $z$ is pure luck in this particular setting, and need not be true in general case.)

Finally, the range of $y$ follows from all three inequalities that constraint the range of $y$, and the result is $\max\{\sqrt{z}, \sqrt[3]{x}\} \leq y \leq 2$. Of course, you can perform sanity-check by recovering the original constraints from this new set of inequalities. As a result,

$$ \iiint_{\mathcal{D}} f(x,y,z) \, dxdydz
= \int_{0}^{4} \int_{0}^{8} \int_{\max\{\sqrt{z}, \sqrt[3]{x}\}}^{2} f(x,y,z) \, dydxdz. $$

Comment: This approach seems purely algebraic. I will try doing a different order this way now, to see if I can make it work.

Comment: So I did dxdydz and got $\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{y^2}\int_{0}^{y^3}$ is that right?

Comment: @Sorfosh, Would you specify which order you are integrating in?

Comment: What do you mean? otherwise, it is ambiguous?

Comment: "So I did dxdydz" ?

Comment: @Sorfosh, Oh, somehow I missed that part, my bad. Perhaps you can highlight any math expression in LaTeX format to make them distinguishable from usual text :) And the correct answer is $$\int_{0}^{4}\int_{\sqrt{z}}^{2}\int_{0}^{y^3}f(x,y,z)\,dxdydz.$$

Comment: First we do $z$, so by the reasoninng in your post we know it is $0<z<4$ which we agree on. Now we want $y$ in terms of z, oh okay, i was going through my reasoning and i go it here :P Thank you. I will have to workout a couple of different examples to see if I can do this. It is a weird approach since i always think of these integrals as regions, and try to see it visually. Thank you for all the help

Comment: @Sorfosh, Glad it helped. And although visual approach is a good method, this often comes at the cost of figuring out the domain geometrically that may take time. Algebraic manipulation bypasses this step at the cost of certain abstraction. I would not say that one is better than another, but rather say that practicing both ways will be the best. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try to expand on @SangchulLee's answer a little bit.

You think through the original problem by realizing that our 3-dimensional region projects down to the region in the $xy$-plane between the $y$-axis and $x=y^3$ [or, equivalently, $y=x^{1/3}$]. In $\Bbb R^3$, $x=y^3$ is a vertical cylinder over this plane curve. For each point in that plane region, a vertical line enters the region at $z=0$ and exits at $z=y^2$. So this surface is a parabolic cylinder, with lines parallel to the $x$-axis. Here's a sketch with the assistance of Mathematica:

[image: 3DRegion]

Indeed, the region lies over the rectangle $R=[0,8]\times [0,4]$ in the $xz$-plane, and the two cylinders intersect along the crease $y=z^{1/2}=x^{1/3}$, which projects to the curve $C$ given by $x^2=z^3$ in the $xz$-plane. If we take a point in $R$, we want to know when a line parallel to the $y$-axis enters and exits our region. If we're below $C$ in $R$, then $z^3<x^2$ and the line enters at $y=x^{1/3}$ and exits at $y=2$. (As a check, if $y\ge x^{1/3}$, then $y\ge z^{1/2}$ as well in this range, so we're "inside" both cylinders.) If we're above $C$ in $R$, then $z^3>x^2$ and the line enters at $y=z^{1/2}$ and exits at $y=2$.

Thus, we end up with the following iterated integral in the order $dy\,dz\,dx$:
$$\int_0^8\int_0^{x^{2/3}}\int_{x^{1/3}}^2 dy\,dz\,dx + \int_0^8\int_{x^{2/3}}^4\int_{z^{1/2}}^2 dy\,dz\,dx.$$

(By the way, you should be able to set up the limits in the orders $dx\,dz\,dy$ or $dx\,dy\,dz$ much more easily.)