# project three dimensional region on to various two dimensional planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

Here's an example from the Stewart text that I'm struggling with. [For those with the text this is on page 1074 from the 8th edition].

Suppose we are given $\int_0^1\int_0^{x^2}\int_0^y f(x,y,z) dzdydx$ and we want to rewrite this iterated integral in other ways.

First the three dimensional region (as given) is clearly

$$E = \{(x,y,z)| \quad 0\le x\le 1\quad 0\le y\le x^2\quad 0\le z\le y\}$$

Then the various different representations are

on the xy-plane $$D_1 = \{(x,y) | 0\le x\le 1; 0\le y\le x^2\}$$
$$D_1 = \{(x,y)| 0\le y\le 1;\sqrt{y}\le x\le 1\}$$
$$D_2 = \{(y,z)|0\le y\le1, 0\le z\le y\}$$
$$D_3 = \{(x,z)|0\le x\le 1, 0\le z \le x^2\}$$

I thought that the two representations for $D_1$ were pretty clear since if $z=0$ then it is still the case that $0\le x\le 1$ and $0\le y\le x^2$ and since the xy plane is precisely when $z=0$ then $D_1$ follows quite naturally.  I don't get the same easy feeling with $D_2$ and $D_3$.

My thought was that because I want to project $E$ onto the yz for $D_2$ then I ought to set $x=0$; then $0\le y\le x^2$ becomes $y=0$.  That doesn't seem very helpful....    I'd appreciate help on this because I think this is the least intuitive concept I've seen in all of calculus.  Thank you!

Comment: No, projecting onto the $ab$-coordinate plane doesn't mean you set $c=0$. You have to ask what points in the $ab$-plane have points in the region lying "over" them (i.e., for what $(a,b)$ is there a point $(a,b,c)$ in the region ... where you have to interpret this notation a bit liberally). So you realize $0\le y\le 1$. Now, for what $z$ is there a point $(x,y,z)$ in the region that projects to $(0,y,z)$? As long as $0\le z\le y$, you have points $(x,y,z)$ with $y\le\sqrt x\le 1$. Sometimes this game does get trickier, though, and you have to split things up into two integrals.

Comment: Okay..... so if I understand you correctly.... as I see it, $D_2$ has the definition that it has because if we have the view point of looking at the $yz$ plane then for any $x$ we will still have $0\le z\le y$.  But since $0\le x\le 1$ and and $0\le y\le x^2$ these facts combined imply that $0\le y\le 1$. 

Similarly, in the $xz$ plane we have $0\le z\le y\le x^2$ so that $0\le z\le x^2$ and $0\le x\le 1$ and this is true for any $y$

Comment: Perhaps my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842286/finding-other-orders-of-triple-integrals/2842326#2842326) will help you some.